# SharePoint 2013 error

Tags: sharepoint

New to SharePoint. I have provided contribute permission for a user in SharePoint 2013. User is unable to see those libraries. It says Error[1]- An unexpected error has been encountered on this Web part

All other user have the same permission and is able to view it. Please suggest.

User is using IE 11. Dont think that's causing the issue.

Comment: I recommend you to check logs, normally in this location:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Logs

Comment: What a horrible title.

Answer (score 0):

Often times that error will have a correlation id associated with it. That correlation id, is written to the logs and can be searched on. It takes some time to get written to the logs but once it does you can find the actual error message.